# How to define exclusive disjunction with Guards Using Haskell

Tags: haskell, truthtable

> this code is to define the exclusive disjunction truth table in haskell

[Click here for more info on exclusive disjunction, XOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table#Logical_disjunction_.28OR.29)
Code:

```
-- truth table concept of logical XOR
exclusiveDisjunction :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
exclusiveDisjunction = x y
    |True True <- False
    |True False <- True 
    |False True <- True 
    |False False <- False
    |otherwise = x y
```

Results:

```
 Ex6^.hs:31:5:
        parse error on input ‘|’
    Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

how to set guards with two boolean values given the xor truth table in haskell syntax ?

Thank you 
Please specify your answer without using haskell built in operators, meaning do not use && ||.

why can't this just be done?

```
exclusiveDisjunction2 :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
exclusiveDisjunction2 x y
    |True True = False
    |True False = True 
    |False True = True 
    |False False = False
```

this is the result after running

```
   Couldn't match expected type ‘Bool -> Bool’ with actual type ‘Bool’
    The function ‘False’ is applied to one argument,
    but its type ‘Bool’ has none
    In the expression: False False
    In a stmt of a pattern guard for
                   an equation for ‘exclusiveDisjunction2’:
      False False
```

Comment: I really like how the range of answers showcases the wide range how verbose/terse the same piece of code can be written in Haskell. You can also see the evolution from verbose to terse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making syntax errors. If you really want to use guards, you can do something like this:

```
exclusiveDisjunction :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
exclusiveDisjunction x y 
    | x == True && y == True = False
    | x == True && y == False = True 
    | x == False && y == True = True
    | x == False && y == False = False
```

But this can be more simply achieved by `case` expressions:

```
exclusiveDisjunction :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
exclusiveDisjunction x y = case (x,y) of
                             (True, True) -> False
                             (True, False) -> True
                             (False, True) -> True
                             (False, False) -> False
```

Or even more simply using the inbuilt `disjunction` operator:

```
exclusiveDisjunction :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
exclusiveDisjunction x y = case (x,y) of
                             (True, True) -> False
                             otherwise -> x || y
```

Comment: `x == True` is equivalent to `x` and `x == False` is equivalen to `not x`.

Comment: @gallais Ah yes, that would be much nicer!

Comment: can you specify this without even the Haskell built in operators, without && || ?please

Comment: @abdulazizalmass: `&&` and `||` (like all infix operators in Haskell) are not built-ins, but mere functions defined in the standard library. **Edit** actually it seems they _are_ built-in in GHC. But they _could_ just as well be library functions.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I would still not say that they are built-ins since they are defined in a library package named `base` which is shipped with GHC.

Comment: @Sibi: I thought so, too. But, though of course `base` does [export](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-Bool.html#v:-38--38-) the boolean functions, their definition seems to come straight from `GHC.Prim`.

Comment: I am testing this now

Answer (score 6):

As @sibi mentioned, you are making syntax errors. But what you are doing is achieved by pattern matching.

```
exclusiveDisjunction :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
exclusiveDisjunction True True = False
exclusiveDisjunction True False = True 
exclusiveDisjunction False True = True 
exclusiveDisjunction False False = False
```

This can be simplified into

```
exclusiveDisjunction :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
exclusiveDisjunction True True = False
exclusiveDisjunction True False = True 
exclusiveDisjunction _ a = a
```

Comment: yours is answering it but I need the guards to answer the question

Comment: 'exclusiveDisjunction2 :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
exclusiveDisjunction2 x y
    |True True = False
    |True False = True 
    |False True = True 
    |False False = False'

Answer (score 6):

There already are good answers, but I wish to show how to implement this in a clearer way, from my point of view.

```
exclusiveDisjunction :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
exclusiveDisjunction True = not
exclusiveDisjunction False = id
```

Comment: Clearer? Really? What about `exclusiveDisjunction = foldr1 (.) . flip drop [not,not] . fromEnum`?

Comment: @user2407038 This is pretty much a matter of opinion, that's why I said "from my point of view". You are free to disagree.

Comment: is not a logical operator?

Comment: @abdulazizalmass It is a function from Data.Bool https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-Bool.html#v:not

Answer (score 5):

The shortest.

```
exclusiveDisjunction :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
exclusiveDisjunction = (/=)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and time

Comment: it does the thing but /= is a built in haskell logical operator.